# How do i create a stored procedure that checks a status, validates, then update status?

Tags: sql-server

I have the following "Handshake" table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Handshake]
(
    [Report Year] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Update Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [Process Time] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Some data here:

```
Report Year Status  Update Time             Process Time
--------------------------------------------------------
2020 1+2    Loaded  2020-08-25 13:10:19.073 NULL
2020 6+8    Loaded  2020-08-25 13:11:30.733 NULL
2020 1+2    Loaded  2020-08-25 13:11:47.257 NULL
```

I have another table, "Fact", that is used to insert the load of these above "Report Years" every time and and a record is inserted into the Handshake table when the back-end process starts to load/updates status from "WIP" to "Loaded" upon load completion, as you can see from the sample Handshake data above.

After the status is `Loaded`, I go in manually every time and run the following queries against `Fact` table to validate the data against other tables.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Report Year Count' 
FROM Fact 
WHERE [Report Year] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] FROM [Report Year])

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'COS Count' 
FROM Fact 
WHERE [Country Code] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] FROM [COS])

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Franchise Count' 
FROM Fact 
WHERE [Style Code] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] FROM [Franchise])

SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Product Count' 
FROM Fact 
WHERE [Style Code] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] FROM [Product])
```

- If the count is 0 for the above queries, then I don't check what the rejects are for those tables.
- If the count is > 0, I run a similar query to identify the rejects.

For example, if Franchise and Product return a count of 1063,

[image: rejects count]

Then I run the following relevant query(s) to identify the missing rejects in those tables:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS 'Franchise - Style Code' 
FROM Fact 
WHERE [Style Code] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] FROM [Franchise])

SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS 'Product - Style Code' 
FROM Fact 
WHERE [Style Code] NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] FROM [Product])
```

[image: rejects sample]

If there are "rejects" (inconsistent data), i send an email to relevant users with what the rejects where so that they can update the tables (i.e. Franchise, COS, Product, Report Year) to include the missing rejects before i proceed with the next step (processing the database).

Instead of continuously performing this validation task manually, I'd like to write a stored procedure that will be triggered by some form of script/job (irrelevant to the scope of this thread for now) that will check the Handshake table for the latest "Loaded" status, run the validation queries, and if there are rejects, update the status for that record in the Handshake table from "Loaded" -> "Rejects". Otherwise, if there are no rejects, update the status to "Good" for no rejects found.

If there are rejects, i'd like to save the results to a scalar variable (i.e. cmd) so that i can extract them later into a csv file of sorts

This is my pseudocode:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[CheckRejects] AS
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000)
BEGIN
    --check Handshake Status. 
    IF Status='Loaded' THEN --RUN Validation Queries
        SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Report Year Count' FROM Fact WHERE [Report Year] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] FROM [Report Year] )
        SELECT COUNT(*) as 'COS Count' FROM Fact WHERE [Country Code] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] FROM [COS] )
        SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Franchise Count' FROM Fact WHERE [Style Code] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] FROM [Franchise] )
        SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Product Count' FROM Fact WHERE [Style Code] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] FROM [Product] )
        
        case 
            when 'Report Year Count' > 0 THEN
                SET Status='Rejects'
                SET @cmd = SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] as 'Report Year' FROM Fact WHERE [Report Year] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] FROM [Report Year] )
            when 'COS Count' > 0 THEN 
                SET Status='Rejects'
                SET @cmd = SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] as 'COS - Country Code' FROM Fact WHERE [Country Code] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] FROM [COS] )
            when 'Franchise Count' > 0 THEN
                SET Status='Rejects'
                SET @cmd = SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] as 'Franchise - Style Code' FROM Fact WHERE [Style Code] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] FROM [Franchise] )
            when 'Product Count' > 0 THEN
                SET Status='Rejects'
                SET @cmd = SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] as 'Product - Style Code' FROM Fact WHERE [Style Code] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] FROM [Product] )
            ELSE SET Status='Good' -- No Rejects, continue to processing DB
END
SELECT @cmd As Rejects
```

Comment: So what is your question? You seem to have a goal - what did you try and what issue did you find for which you need help? SO is not a free code-writing service. Rather than do everything at once, I suggest you break your goal into pieces that you can address - simple divide and conquer give that you already have some queries written. Just stitch the logic together to run them and act on the results.

Comment: @SMor my goal is to create a SP like the one i have above. i have tried the above SP, but it results in errors. Need help in formulating it better to run properly

Comment: @SMor i just realized that the last sentence was cutoff in my post. i have updated my post with what is needed exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to your data/schema so this is an untested attempt, but you could try something like the following:

```
DECLARE
    @ValidationStatus VARCHAR(10),
    @ReportYearCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @CosCountCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000),
    @ProductCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000);

SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Handshake Validations --
SELECT TOP 1
    @ReportYearCmd = CASE WHEN Report_Year_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] AS [Report Year] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] );'
    END,
    @CosCountCmd = CASE WHEN COS_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] );' 
    END,
    @FranchiseCountCmd = CASE WHEN  Franchise_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Franchise - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    @ProductCountCmd = CASE WHEN Product_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Product - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    @ValidationStatus = CASE
        WHEN ( Report_Year_Count = 0 AND COS_Count = 0 AND Franchise_Count = 0 AND Product_Count = 0 ) THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Rejects'
    END
FROM [Handshake] 
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT 
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] ) ), 0 ) AS [Report_Year_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [COS_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Franchise_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Product_Count]

) AS [ValidationCounts]
WHERE 
    [Handshake].[Status] = 'Loaded'
ORDER BY
    [Handshake].[Update Time] DESC;
        
-- Return validation results --

SELECT
    ISNULL( @ValidationStatus, 'Good' ) AS ValidationStatus,
    @ReportYearCmd AS ReportYearCmd,
    @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd,
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS FranchiseCountCmd,
    @ProductCountCmd AS ProductCountCmd;
```

**UPDATE:**

*If I want to update the Handshake table with the ValidationStatus as part of the Stored Procedure, where can I do that?*

Try the following:

```
DECLARE
    @ReportYearCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @CosCountCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000),
    @ProductCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000);

WITH Validations AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Handshake] WHERE [Status] = 'Loaded' AND [Update Time] = ( SELECT MAX( [Update Time] ) FROM Handshake )
)
UPDATE Validations 
SET 
    @ReportYearCmd = CASE WHEN Report_Year_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] AS [Report Year] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] );'
    END,
    @CosCountCmd = CASE WHEN COS_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] );' 
    END,
    @FranchiseCountCmd = CASE WHEN  Franchise_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Franchise - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    @ProductCountCmd = CASE WHEN Product_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Product - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    [Status] = CASE
        WHEN ( Report_Year_Count = 0 AND COS_Count = 0 AND Franchise_Count = 0 AND Product_Count = 0 ) THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Rejects'
    END
FROM [Validations] 
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT 
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] ) ), 0 ) AS [Report_Year_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [COS_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Franchise_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Product_Count]

) AS [ValidationCounts];

-- Return validation results --

SELECT
    @ReportYearCmd AS ReportYearCmd,
    @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd,
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS FranchiseCountCmd,
    @ProductCountCmd AS ProductCountCmd;

-- Optionally email the dynamic statements to someone --

IF @ReportYearCmd IS NOT NULL
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name = 'your_dbmail_profile',
        @recipients = 'email@domain.com',
        @subject = 'ReportYear Load Rejects',
        @execute_query_database = 'your_db_name',
        @query = @ReportYearCmd,
        @query_result_header = 0,
        @query_attachment_filename = 'ReportYearRejects.csv',
        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
        @query_result_separator = ';',
        @exclude_query_output = 1,
        @query_result_no_padding = 1;

IF @CosCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name = 'your_dbmail_profile',
        @recipients = 'email@domain.com',
        @subject = 'COS Load Rejects',
        @execute_query_database = 'your_db_name',
        @query = @CosCountCmd,
        @query_result_header = 0,
        @query_attachment_filename = 'COSRejects.csv',
        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
        @query_result_separator = ';',
        @exclude_query_output = 1,
        @query_result_no_padding = 1;

IF @FranchiseCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name = 'your_dbmail_profile',
        @recipients = 'email@domain.com',
        @subject = 'Franchise Load Rejects',
        @execute_query_database = 'your_db_name',
        @query = @FranchiseCountCmd,
        @query_result_header = 0,
        @query_attachment_filename = 'FranchiseRejects.csv',
        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
        @query_result_separator = ';',
        @exclude_query_output = 1,
        @query_result_no_padding = 1;

IF @ProductCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    EXEC msdb..sp_send_dbmail 
        @profile_name = 'your_dbmail_profile',
        @recipients = 'email@domain.com',
        @subject = 'Product Load Rejects',
        @execute_query_database = 'your_db_name',
        @query = @ProductCountCmd,
        @query_result_header = 0,
        @query_attachment_filename = 'ProductRejects.csv',
        @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
        @query_result_separator = ';',
        @exclude_query_output = 1,
        @query_result_no_padding = 1;
```

Comment: oh this is great! btw instead of checking for a specific report year at `AND [Handshake].[Report Year] = '2020 1+2';`, can the stored procedure simply check for the latest (most recent) update time? is it `AND MAX [Handshake].[Update Time]`?

Comment: @Cataster Does Handshake have a Identity Column or something that can be sorted to perform a `TOP 1` for the most current record?

Comment: no it doesn't :/ nothing really counts as unique here except probably the Update Time, but even that is an iffy column. I was thinking in the stored procedure there can be a query that sorts the update time by DESC and picks the top 1 that way

Comment: Without an ID that would be my approach as well.

Comment: @Cataster I have modified my example to a `TOP 1` with a `[Handshake.][Update Time] DESC` ordering.

Comment: i think this is excellent. could you elaborate on this statement here? `I restricted my example to a single record, however, you'll need to figure out how to restrict your Handshake table so you don't overwrite the @...Cmd variables` If im not mistaken, you're saying you're only selecting one record from the Handshake table? if thats the case, i think thats exactly what i want anyways, hence the Top 1 and DESC Update Time right? :)

Comment: if i want to update the Handshake table with the ValidationStatus as part of the Stored Procedure, where can i do that?

Comment: @Cataster The "restricted" comment is irrelevant now given the use of TOP 1. I'll update my example to remove that. Let me look into the status update and get back to you.

Comment: @Cataster Check out the UPDATE to my example to handle the updating of `Handshake.Status` in the same call. Note: `@ValidationStatus` variable is no longer needed.

Comment: Beautiful! one thing is when i ran it twice, it updated another slightly older record. can we restrict it so that it has to be "Loaded" AND the Update Time most recent so that no matter how many times it runs, only the latest update time record updates?

Comment: @Cataster, I modified my second example to accomodate your additional request. I added `AND [Update Time] = ( SELECT MAX( [Update Time] ) FROM Handshake )` to the Validations subquery.

Comment: Perfect! if i may ask, currently this SP produces the SQL statements to generate the rejects. could we also generate the actual rejects as part of this SP, displaying rejects like i have in the second set of images in my post? So simply an addition on top of the current SP to generate the rejects into a temp/staging  table. the table lets say would be called `Rejects`.

Comment: Sure, you could do something like `INSERT INTO Rejects ( [RejectValue] )
EXEC ( @ReportYearCmd );`

Comment: RejectValue would be the column name?

Comment: That's just a name I made up. RejectValue would be replaced with whatever the actual column name (and table name) where the value will be inserted in your temp/staging table.

Comment: Gotcha. If I wanted to insert all @cmd rejects into target Rejects table, would I have to insert separately for each reject? Or can I.do this in one insert statement for all @cmd's/reject columns? E.g. `INSERT INTO Rejects ( [Report Year Reject],  [COS Reject] ) EXEC ( @ReportYearCmd, @CosCmd );` and if the @cmd is NULL (I.e. theres no rejects), would it leave the insertion NULL automatically or would I have to check each @cmd if its NULL prior to insert?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221182/discussion-between-critical-error-and-cataster).

Comment: Hey, could you help me out with one more thing? I want to display the results (rejects) directly instead of the sql statements generated. I removed each of the declared variables on the switch condition, and removed the quotes around the sql statements, but i am getting incorrect syntax near CASE. i have posted another thread here if you'd like to answer in a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890925/export-stored-procedure-results-into-a-staging-table