# Export stored procedure results into a table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following stored procedure that generates SQL statements based on certain conditions.

I'd like for the SQL statements to also return the actual results into a table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rejects](
    [Report Year] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [COS - Country Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Franchise - Style Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Product - Style Code] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

How could I do that?

```
DECLARE
    @ReportYearCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @CosCountCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000),
    @ProductCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000);

WITH Validations AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Handshake] WHERE [Status] = 'Loaded' AND [Update Time] = ( SELECT MAX( [Update Time] ) FROM Handshake )
)
UPDATE Validations 
SET 
    @ReportYearCmd = CASE WHEN Report_Year_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] AS [Report Year] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] );'
    END,
    @CosCountCmd = CASE WHEN COS_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] );' 
    END,
    @FranchiseCountCmd = CASE WHEN  Franchise_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Franchise - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    @ProductCountCmd = CASE WHEN Product_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Product - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    [Status] = CASE
        WHEN ( Report_Year_Count = 0 AND COS_Count = 0 AND Franchise_Count = 0 AND Product_Count = 0 ) THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Rejects'
    END
FROM [Validations] 
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT 
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] ) ), 0 ) AS [Report_Year_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [COS_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Franchise_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Product_Count]

) AS [ValidationCounts];

-- Return validation sql statements --

SELECT
    @ReportYearCmd AS ReportYearCmd,
    @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd,
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS FranchiseCountCmd,
    @ProductCountCmd AS ProductCountCmd;
```

Basically, right after this part:

```
-- Return validation sql statements --

SELECT
    @ReportYearCmd AS ReportYearCmd,
    @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd,
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS FranchiseCountCmd,
    @ProductCountCmd AS ProductCountCmd;
```

Currently, when I execute this SP I get something like:

```
ReportYearCmd CosCountCmd FranchiseCountCmd  ProductCountCmd

NULL          SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] )        NULL               SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Product - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] )
```

I'd like to return the actual result, i.e. if the Cmd is NOT NULL, as in the example above, return CosCountCmd and ProductCountCmd data:

```
Report Year COS - Country Code   Franchise - Style Code   Product - Style Code 
NULL        reject1              NULL                     Rejectxy
NULL        reject2              NULL                     Reject1234
NULL        NULL                 NULL                     Reject567
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/* Execute the dynamic SQL to return their resultsets if cmd variable IS NOT NULL */

IF @ReportYearCmd IS NOT NULL
    EXEC ( @ReportYearCmd );

IF @CosCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    EXEC ( @CosCountCmd );

IF @FranchiseCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    EXEC ( @FranchiseCountCmd );

IF @ProductCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    EXEC ( @ProductCountCmd );
```

**Note:** This potentially returns four different resultsets--not a pivoted result.

**EDIT:**

*Return a single resultset for each reject category.*

This is about as close as you're going to get without having to do a lot of extra work:

```
DECLARE @Rejects TABLE ( 
    [Report Year] VARCHAR(50),
    [COS - Country Code] VARCHAR(50),
    [Product - Style Code] VARCHAR(50),
    [Franchise - Style Code] VARCHAR(50)
);

IF @ReportYearCmd IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO @Rejects ( [Report Year] ) EXEC ( @ReportYearCmd );
    
IF @CosCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO @Rejects ( [COS - Country Code] ) EXEC ( @CosCountCmd );
    
IF @FranchiseCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO @Rejects ( [Franchise - Style Code] ) EXEC ( @FranchiseCountCmd );
    
IF @ProductCountCmd IS NOT NULL
    INSERT INTO @Rejects ( [Product - Style Code] ) EXEC ( @ProductCountCmd );

-- Return resultset.
SELECT * FROM @Rejects;
```

Returns something like:

```
+-------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| Report Year | COS - Country Code | Franchise - Style Code | Product - Style Code |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| NULL        | reject1            | NULL                   | NULL                 |
| NULL        | reject2            | NULL                   | NULL                 |
| NULL        | NULL               | NULL                   | Rejectxy             |
| NULL        | NULL               | NULL                   | Reject1234           |
| NULL        | NULL               | NULL                   | Reject567            |
+-------------+--------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
```

Your calling application will need to handle NULL values when processing the results as there is no easy way to "roll-up" NULL columns/rows to reduce the results as shown in your expectation.

Comment: I have updated my post with the table i'd like this data to get inserted into with an example at the end

Comment: @Cataster You're wanting a single resultset with one column for each cmd?

Comment: yep! so what you currently have is good but its generated into its own result set (4 different result set). instead, i want the results to be inserted into one table, per the column associated with the results

Comment: this one is resulting in syntax error: `TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[Rejects]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Rejects] (
    [Report Year]
      ,[COS - Country Code]
      ,[Franchise - Style Code]
      ,[Product - Style Code]
)
VALUES (
 IF @ReportYearCmd IS NOT NULL
  EXEC ( @ReportYearCmd );

 IF @CosCmd IS NOT NULL
  EXEC ( @CosCmd );

 IF @FranchiseCmd IS NOT NULL
  EXEC ( @FranchiseCmd );

 IF @ProductCmd IS NOT NULL
  EXEC ( @ProductCmd );
)`

Comment: @Cataster, you cannot do what you're attempting to do there. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Cataster, You can modify my example to replace the table variable to use your actual one.

Comment: Man thank you so much!!! finally this is exactly what i needed!! btw if i want to declare the existing rejects table as a variable, something like this: @Rejects = [dbo].[Rejects], is that doable?

Comment: @Cataster, No, you cannot do that. You'll need to modify my example like: `INSERT INTO dbo.Rejects ( [Franchise - Style Code] ) EXEC ( @FranchiseCountCmd );`

Comment: i have one more request: i am truncating that Rejects table first prior to the insertion since users will want to see new data. If they fix the rejects, they would run the SP again and the Table will show NULLs. however, if the rejects arent fixed, the Rejects table should retain the rejects. i need a conditional statement here: `IF Validations.[Status] != 'Reject(s)' TRUNCATE [dbo].Rejects `. am i using Validation here correct? or do i have to do this: `if (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Handshake].[Status] != 'Reject(s)' AND [Update Time] = ( SELECT MAX( [Update Time] ) FROM Handshake ) Truncate ..`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221532/discussion-between-critical-error-and-cataster).

Comment: sure, im in chat

Comment: Is there no way to add something to the INSERT queries so that the results are around the same level as prior column(s)? For example, Rejectxy , in your example output table, is currently on row3. is it not possible make it on row1, by first checking wherever there is NULL at the top to insert before creating a new row?

Comment: @Cataster Because they are four different columns for each set of rejects you'd have to do some fairly extensive codeing to do so and I wouldnt be so sure it's worth the effort.

Comment: Gotcha, I guess it's not super necessary at this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
) AS [ValidationCounts];
-- insertion here-
Insert into temp_table (col1, col2, col3, ...)
SELECT
    @ReportYearCmd AS ReportYearCmd,
    @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd,
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS FranchiseCountCmd,
    @ProductCountCmd AS ProductCountCmd;
```

Comment: can you check it again. I changed the syntax little bit

Comment: Does this return the actual query result? ive updated my post to include the expected output. i'd like to return the results for only those such columns NOT NULL, as in the example provided at end of the post