# Why is the #TEMP Table not showing up?

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure as follows that I'd like to export its results in a table.

```
DECLARE
    @ReportYearCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @CosCountCmd VARCHAR(1000),
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000),
    @ProductCountCmd AS VARCHAR(1000);

WITH Validations AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Handshake] WHERE [Status] = 'Loaded' AND [Update Time] = ( SELECT MAX( [Update Time] ) FROM Handshake )
)
UPDATE Validations 
SET 
    @ReportYearCmd = CASE WHEN Report_Year_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Report Year] AS [Report Year] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] );'
    END,
    @CosCountCmd = CASE WHEN COS_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] );' 
    END,
    @FranchiseCountCmd = CASE WHEN  Franchise_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Franchise - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    @ProductCountCmd = CASE WHEN Product_Count = 0 THEN NULL 
        ELSE 'SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Product - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] );' 
    END,
    [Status] = CASE
        WHEN ( Report_Year_Count = 0 AND COS_Count = 0 AND Franchise_Count = 0 AND Product_Count = 0 ) THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Rejects'
    END
FROM [Validations] 
OUTER APPLY (

    SELECT 
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Report Year] WHERE [Report Year].[Report Year] = [Fact].[Report Year] ) ), 0 ) AS [Report_Year_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [COS_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Franchise] WHERE [Franchise].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Franchise_Count],
        ISNULL( ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] ) ), 0 ) AS [Product_Count]

) AS [ValidationCounts];

-- Return validation sql statements --

SELECT
    @ReportYearCmd AS ReportYearCmd,
    @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd,
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS FranchiseCountCmd,
    @ProductCountCmd AS ProductCountCmd;

-- Insert actual SQL statament results into Rejects Table --

IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE #TEMP END
SELECT
    ReportYearCmd, CosCountCmd, FranchiseCountCmd, ProductCountCmd
INTO #TEMP
FROM (
    SELECT 
    @ReportYearCmd AS ReportYearCmd,
    @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd,
    @FranchiseCountCmd AS FranchiseCountCmd,
    @ProductCountCmd AS ProductCountCmd
    ) AS [RejectsTable]
```

This only returns the validation statements from the first select statement, but I don't see a RejectTable showing the actual rejects from those SQL statements...

Currently, when I execute this SP I get something like:

```
ReportYearCmd CosCountCmd FranchiseCountCmd  ProductCountCmd

NULL          SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] )        NULL               SELECT DISTINCT [Style Code] AS [Product - Style Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [Product] WHERE [Product].[Style Code] = [Fact].[Style Code] )
```

I'd like to return the actual result, i.e. if the Cmd is NOT NULL, as in the example above, return CosCountCmd and ProductCountCmd data:

```
COS - Country Code     Product - Style Code 
reject1         Rejectxy
reject2         Reject1234
NULL            Reject567
```

I followed some of the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107827/insert-data-into-temp-table-with-query) but none of them seem to work for me...

Comment: Temp tables go out of scope at the end of the SP... so it will gone by the time you return.

Comment: @DaleK oh...but i have the GO after it...shouldnt that make a difference? where am i supposed to place it then

Comment: GO is a client command to separate statements. So does nothing.

Comment: You either have to create a *real* table for returning the results via, or create your temp table in the calling context because it is available for any called SPs.

Comment: @DaleK, i see. can you elaborate on this? `create your temp table in the calling context`

Comment: Create it before you call your SP.

Comment: @DaleK oh i see... i guess its easier to just create the table itself then

Comment: @DaleK one more question. how can i unload the actual results into the table of the validation sql statements that are selected?

Comment: Depends on your use case, I use both ways depending on my situation.

Comment: "how can i unload the actual results into the table of the validation sql statements that are selected" - sorry not sure what you mean by this. Might need another question.

Comment: @DaleK updated my pos at the endt with what i am currently getting and what i am looking for

Comment: So you want to execute the SQL statements you have built if they fail validation?

Comment: @DaleK Yep! so for example, this is what the `SELECT @CosCountCmd AS CosCountCmd`, statement currently returns: `SELECT DISTINCT [Country Code] AS [COS - Country Code] FROM [Fact] WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM [COS] WHERE [COS].[Country Code] = [Fact].[Country Code] )`. but i need the actual execution of this select

Comment: OK, so that requires Dynamic SQL - which I suggest you check out some tutorials for. And then another question. This question was only about why the temp table wasn't showing.

Comment: @DaleK ok ill post another question. should i delete this question then? or would you like to submit an answer and i'll mark it?

Comment: I'll answer. Another option to consider, depending on how it suits your system, is writing a CLR function to evaluate your validation rules. I've done that before, and then have more control over it.

Comment: @DaleK interesting! could you tell me more about it in another question? actually, i think this question here should already be suitable for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63890925/export-stored-procedure-results-into-a-staging-table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221484/discussion-between-dale-k-and-cataster).

Comment: @DaleK sure i am there now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Local temporary tables are visible only in the current session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#temporary-tables). And as such:

> A local temporary table created in a stored procedure is dropped automatically when the stored procedure is finished.

In fact a global temp table (defined using a double number sign e.g. `##temp`) will probably do what you want:

> Global temporary tables are automatically dropped when the session that created the table ends and all other tasks have stopped referencing them.

Otherwise you could define a temp table in the calling scope i.e. before you call your SP or use a regular table.

Comment: thank you. i found this answer here too, and apparently an extra # makes a huge difference? https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893172/8397835 so ##TEMP means its more of a permanent table?

Comment: Thats a global temp table - all explained in the reference I linked to. In fact that might do what you need.